# How to recursively search all files in a directory and sub-directories using PowerShell?

Tags: linux, powershell, recursion, .net-core, tree

I'm not understanding where the recursion is occurring nor how it's used in the below `tree` function (which is meant to emulate some of the linux `tree` command results).

From the `tree` function, how are files (or file names and their path) passed to, here, a `SearchString` function?

for context, here's a `REPL` session demonstrating the end-goal on a single file:  getting the `PSPath` property for a file, and using that property for a simple `regex`.

Session transcript:

```
posh> $dir = "/home/nicholas/Calibre Library/Microsoft Office User/549 (1476)"
posh> $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir –File
posh> $files.Length
3
posh> $files[0].Extension
.txt
posh> $files[0].PSPath
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::/home/nicholas/Calibre Library/Microsoft Office User/549 (1476)/549 - Microsoft Office User.txt
posh> $pattern = '(?=.*?foo)(?=.*?bar)'
posh> $string = Get-Content $files[0]
posh> $string | Select-String $pattern
```

This file doesn't have any "foo" and "bar" matches.  The goal is to search the entire `Calibre` library using `PowerShell` as above.

---

large output from a `tree` of the `Calibre` library trimmed to a single result:

```
    Directory: /home/nicholas/Calibre Library/Microsoft Office User/548 (1474)

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-----           2/20/2021  3:22 AM         159883 548 - Microsoft Office User.txt
-----           2/20/2021  2:13 AM         351719 cover.jpg
-----           2/20/2021  2:39 AM           1126 metadata.opf

posh> ./worker.ps1
```

How is the above file and path passed to the `SearchString` function?

the goal being to iterate through the entire library and search all plain-text file.  (Assumption being that plain-text files have a ".txt" extension.)

library code:

```
function SearchFile($dir,$file)
{
    $path =  [string]::Concat($dir,"/",$file)
    $pattern='(?=.*?foo)(?=.*?bar)'
    $string = Get-Content $path
    $result = $string | Select-String $pattern
    $result
}


function tree($dir)
{
    "$dir"
    $tree = Get-ChildItem -Recurse
    $tree = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse
    # get any files and invoke SearchFile here ?
    $tree
}
```

worker code:

```
. /home/nicholas/powershell/functions/library.ps1


$dir = "/home/nicholas/Calibre Library"

tree $dir
```

The execution of the `SearchFile` function should be triggered when a ".txt" file is found.  That logic is missing.  But the larger missing piece is how to invoke `SearchFile` from the `tree` function so that every file gets searched.

How is that done?  Leaving aside the file-type or file extension.  Not seeing where the recursion occurs.

Answer (score 4):

You are really overcomplicating things.  You can do this very easily by using Get-ChildItem to find your txt files recursively in $dir path and then piping these FileInfo objects directly to Select-String cmdlet which accepts pipeline input and will grab the PSPath from the FileInfo object being passed to it and do its thing.  Select-String will do this for every object that Get-ChildItem sends to it which are FileInfo objects for all txt files found recursively in your $dir path.

```
$dir = '/home/nicholas/Calibre Library/Microsoft Office User/549 (1476)'
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $dir -Filter *.txt |
    Select-String -Pattern '(?=.*?foo)(?=.*?bar)'
```

Answer (score 2):

`Get-ChildItem` already does the recursion for you when you specify the `-Recurse` argument. For your code it doesn't make any difference. You get a linear list of all file informations that you can process using `ForEach-Object` in the same way as if you didn't specify `-Recurse`.

> The SearchFile function should be executed when a ".txt" file is found.

Use the `-Filter` parameter to specify `*.txt`. Also when you want to get files only, always pass `-File`. This allows the filesystem provider to already skip directories, which is faster and also more correct (in theory there could be directories named e. g. `foo.txt` which would let `SearchFile` run into an error).

```
function tree($dir)
{
    "$dir"
    Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse -File -Filter *.txt | ForEach-Object {
        SearchFile -dir $_.Directory.PSPath -file $_.Name
    }        
}
```

I don't know why your function `SearchFile` has separate parameters for directory and file name. The `Get-ChildItem` already outputs the full path in `$_.PSPath`. It doesn't make much sense to split the path apart and join it together again in `SearchFile`. I suggest you replace them by a single `Path` parameter.